# application crash when I used layout_toRightOf in android

Tags: java, android

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#e6e6e6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/headerbar"
         android:padding="10dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
          android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewtest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:text="@string/appsetting"
            android:background="@drawable/pinkbuttonbackground"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"               
            android:textAppearance="@dimen/textfontsize" />

    </RelativeLayout>

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_buttonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/okButton" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#be0054"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/background_textfield"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_autoComplete"
        android:text="@string/chooseStation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#d70261" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

![][1]

![enter image description here][2]

my application crash when I write l **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"**
my textView1 is textview name "choose station " actually there is autocomplete field whch is below the textview .I need to shift that on right ..when I used this **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"**
it creash ..
**here is log**

```
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1286)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:294)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:314)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-01 13:20:56.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**expected output**

Comment: You have already written `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_autoComplete"` and then when you write `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"`, it creates circular dependency

Comment: show the design what you want to achieve

Comment: wait for minut I will tell you

Comment: this is expected result...Actually i dont want text field not touch to width

Comment: try the answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` :

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textfield"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:text="chooseStation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#d70261" />
```

Comment: actually it is not crashing.but autocomplete is touching the end of width

Comment: are you getting expected result? what do you mean by *end of width* ?? end of  the screen ?

Comment: I need some padding so that it will not touch the end of width.wait I will give example as you see my label having some margin in "choose label" from left .I need some margin from end in autocomlete

Comment: give `android:layout_marginRight="30dp"`